# How to remove non-alphabetic characters and convert all letter to lowercase in R?

Tags: regex, r

In the following string:

```
"I may opt for a yam for Amy, May, and Tommy."
```

How to remove non-alphabetic characters and convert all letter to lowercase and sort the letters within each word in R?

Meanwhile, I try to sort words in sentence and removes the duplicates.

Comment: Could you show us [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: Can you provide an example string and the expected output? To convert to lowercase, just use `tolower`.

Comment: "sort the letters within each word"?

Answer (score 6):

`stringr` will let you work on all character sets in R and at C-speed, and `magrittr` will let you use a piping idiom that works well for your needs:

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

txt <- "I may opt for a yam for Amy, May, and Tommy."

txt %>% 
  str_to_lower %>%                                            # lowercase
  str_replace_all("[[:punct:][:digit:][:cntrl:]]", "") %>%    # only alpha
  str_replace_all("[[:space:]]+", " ") %>%                    # single spaces
  str_split(" ") %>%                                          # tokenize
  extract2(1) %>%                                             # str_split returns a list
  sort %>%                                                    # sort
  unique                                                      # unique words

  ## [1] "a"     "amy"   "and"   "for"   "i"     "may"   "opt"   "tommy" "yam"
```

Comment: I wonder if maybe `txt %>% 
  str_to_lower %>%    str_replace_all("[^[:alpha:] ']", "") %>%  str_split(" +") %>%  extract2(1) %>%    sort %>% 
  unique`  maybe more condensed.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
unique(stri_sort(stri_trans_tolower(stri_extract_all_words(txt, simplify = TRUE))))
```

Which gives:

```
## [1] "a"     "amy"   "and"   "for"   "i"     "may"   "opt"   "tommy" "yam"
```

**Update**

As per mentionned by @DavidArenburg, I overlooked the "*sort the letters within words*" part of your question. You didn't provide a desired output and no immediate application comes to mind but, assuming you want to identify which words have a matching counterpart (string distance of 0):

```
unique(stri_sort(stri_trans_tolower(stri_extract_all_words(txt, simplify = TRUE)))) %>%
  stringdistmatrix(., ., useNames = "strings", method = "qgram") %>%

#       a amy and for i may opt tommy yam
# a     0   2   2   4 2   2   4     6   2
# amy   2   0   4   6 4   0   6     4   0
# and   2   4   0   6 4   4   6     8   4
# for   4   6   6   0 4   6   4     6   6
# i     2   4   4   4 0   4   4     6   4
# may   2   0   4   6 4   0   6     4   0
# opt   4   6   6   4 4   6   0     4   6
# tommy 6   4   8   6 6   4   4     0   4
# yam   2   0   4   6 4   0   6     4   0

  apply(., 1, function(x) sum(x == 0, na.rm=TRUE)) 

# a   amy   and   for     i   may   opt tommy   yam 
# 1     3     1     1     1     3     1     1     3
```

Words with more than one `0` per row (`"amy", "may", "yam"`) have a *scrambled* counterpart.

Comment: I tend to use `stringr` now since it uses `stringi` under the hood but that function but that `stri_extract_all_words` looks really handy. I may have to go back to using `stringi`.

Comment: Yes. `stringr` is simpler but I find `stringi` much more flexible.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I think you both ignored the "*sort the letters within each word*" part

Comment: But what does that even mean?

Comment: @DavidArenburg The OP does ask for the sorting of letters within words.  This makes no sense to me.  The post is some what barebones.  I think if the OP provided a desired output their question would be much more clear because what they ask for doesn't have an apparent immediate application.

Answer (score 4):

```
str <- "I may opt for a yam for Amy, May, and Tommy."

## Clean the words (just keep letters and convert to lowercase)
words <- strsplit(tolower(gsub("[^A-Za-z ]", "", str)), " ")[[1]]

## split the words into characters and sort them
sortedWords <- sapply(words, function(word) sort(unlist(strsplit(word, ""))))

## Join the sorted letters back together
sapply(sortedWords, paste, collapse="")

# i     may     opt     for       a     yam     for     amy     may     and 
# "i"   "amy"   "opt"   "for"     "a"   "amy"   "for"   "amy"   "amy"   "adn" 
# tommy 
# "mmoty" 

## If you want to convert result back to string
do.call(paste, lapply(sortedWords, paste, collapse=""))
# [1] "i amy opt for a amy for amy amy adn mmoty"
```

Answer (score 4):

The **qdap** package that I maintain has the `bag_o_words` function that works well for this:

```
txt <- "I may opt for a yam for Amy, May, and Tommy."

library(qdap)

unique(sort(bag_o_words(txt)))

## [1] "a"     "amy"   "and"   "for"   "i"     "may"   "opt"   "tommy" "yam"
```